# Objective-C: How do you append a string to an NSMutableString?

Tags: objective-c

URL Download

> http://code.google.com/p/mwiphonesdk/source/browse/#svn/trunk/iMADE/PrepTasks/08

I have code at the location at the link above and I am using *NSMutableString* to append strings as data is downloaded. But I am finding that using appendString does not increase the length of the mutable string. I must be doing something wrong.

And when I am done I need to convert *NSMutableString* to *NSString* to return it. I have looked for examples to do this but I do not see any yet.

I am most familiar with Java and C# where there is a StringBuffer/StringBuilder which allows you to append pieces and them simply call toString at the end to get a String. It does not appear to be this easy in Objective-C.

```
NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

#pragma mark TODO Confirm this is appending a value to the mutable string
[self.mutableString appendString:str];

NSLog(@"str length: %d, %d", [str length], [self.mutableString length]);
```

Above is the section of code that calls appendString.

I see that str has a length > 0 but calling appendString does not increase the length of self.mutableString.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you initialize `self.mutableString`?  Try doing it with a local `NSMutableString` variable instead.

Comment: When you say "does increase" do you mean "does **not** increase"?

Comment: Yes, I was missing a not. I could try using a local instead, but doesn't it have to be an instance variable? It is used by multiple methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for having an `NSMutableString*` and needing to return an `NSString*`, the former is a subclass of the latter so anywhere you see an `NSString*` an `NSMutableString*` will suffice as-is.

Your code looks OK from what you've posted. The only thing I can think of is that perhaps there isn't any data to speak of when initializing the `str` variable. In such a case appending an empty string will do nothing to mutableString.

You'll also want to make sure `self.mutableString` has been properly allocated and initialized. You can send messages to `NSObject*`s that are `nil` which may be misleading when `[self.mutableString length]` returns 0.

Comment: The answer is correct, but you might want to be careful when returning an `NSMutableString *` as `NSString *`. Even though the type says it's an `NSString` it's still a `NSMutableString` under the hood. Someone can cast the returned `NSString` it to an `NSMutableString` and change the data it contains without you knowing. Obviuosly that's a bad idea, but you know how we are under stress. Better to prevent it in the first place. Make sure you `return [self.mutableString copy]` and you should be safe.

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed the problem. I simply was not initializing the NSMutableString value and it was transparently not doing anything.

Before appending the string I put the following code.

```
if (_mutableString == nil){
    _mutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}
```

Thanks everyone for answering. And it is good to know that I can use NSMutableString in place of NSString. (that is too easy) :)

Comment: It's better to initialize mutableString in your `init` method.  Otherwise, you'll get unexpected results elsewhere.