# NSMutableString append is not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C: How do you append a string to an NSMutableString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614481/objective-c-how-do-you-append-a-string-to-an-nsmutablestring)

I have a NSMutableArray. I want to extract all elements of this NSMutable array and append it in to a string. My following code is not working. String is not append to the variable. Also I am using automatic reference counting feature in this project.

```
NSMutableString *theString = [NSMutableString string];

for(int i=0; i<[self.incomingMessages count]; i++) {
      id object = [self.incomingMessages objectAtIndex: i];
      [theString appendString:(NSString*)object];
}

NSLog(@"the appended string: %@", theString);
[self.incomingMessages removeAllObjects];
```

How can I append the stored strings into the theString variable. Whats is the mistake I have done?

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: Same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614481/objective-c-how-do-you-append-a-string-to-an-nsmutablestring

Comment: Ast he link points out, there might be an allocation problem.

Comment: Are you sure that object is of type NSString? To test this: `[object isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]`

Comment: how many objects do you have in the `incomingMessages` property? is the `theString` has valid pointer or just `nil`?

Comment: yes I double checked it is NSString

Comment: incomingMessages has 1026 elements

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
 NSMutableString *theString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init ];
```

Try to print and see if your **object** is string

Comment: I printed. The object is a string.So no prob with the "object" variable. I tried [[NSMutableString alloc]init ] but still the string is not appended.

Comment: so you are sure that all you objects in incomingMessages array are strings?

Comment: There is already an `NSMutableString` created by `[NSMutableString string]`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to initialize your `theString` like this?

```
NSMutableString *theString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
```

Comment: I tried this. but no succecss

Comment: There is _already_ a string being created with `[NSMutableString string]`.